# Props interdependance in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to add some linking dependencies between my props in my VueJS component.

For example in my component on props declaration, i would like to stipulate that if a prop is present, then another one should be required, but not required at all if the previous props is not there.

```
props: {
    url: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    isShared: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    isSharedByOtherMember: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    archivedId: {
      type: String,
      required: isSharedByOtherMember ? true : false, // This is not working, bit is there a way to do so ?
    },
```

After reading [vuejs docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Validation) :

> Note that props are validated before a component instance is created, so instance properties (e.g. data, computed, etc) will not be available inside default or validator functions.

Is there a way to still do this in props declaration for better readability/understandability after ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would suggest using default values for each dependent prop.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the validator property for prop.

Vue docs has this example: (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Validation)

```
// Custom validator function
propF: {
  validator: function (value) {
    // The value must match one of these strings
    return ['success', 'warning', 'danger'].indexOf(value) !== -1
  }
}
```

You could define a validator method in Vue methods section.

Something like this:

```
export default {
  props: {
    isSharedByOtherMember: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    archivedId: {
      type: String,
      default: null,
      required: false,
      validator: this.validateArchiveId(),
      errorMessage: 'Archived ID required when isSharedByOtherMember has value of true.'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    validateArchiveId () {
      return this.isSharedByOtherMember
    }
  }
}
```